# How to mitigate The specified child already has a parent (IllegalStateException) Error?

Tags: android, android-layout, illegalstateexception

At first i was trying to re-adjust my LinearLayout and view programatically as posted on this question.

[Adjusting linear layout programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970826/moving-layout-position-programatically-in-linear-layout/20971226?noredirect=1#comment31505948_20971226)

How ever this raise another exception, specifically IllegalStateException (saying that "The specified child already has a parent")

The error occured in my Adapter specifically in this part (the second if statement):

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     View row = convertView;
     if (row == null) {
             LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_item, parent, false);
     }

     wrapper = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.wrapper);

     textChat = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textMessage);
     thumbPhoto = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.thumbPhoto);

     ChatString chat = getItem(position);
     if(chat.mLeft){
         textChat.setText(chat.mText); 
     }else{
         wrapper.removeViewAt(1);
         wrapper.addView(thumbPhoto, 0);
         textChat.setText(chat.mText);
     }
     return row;
 }
```

And this is how the adapter is used within its root view (i suspect this would be the culprit, but i am not to sure on what to do about it):

*This piece of code reside within a onPostExecute() of an AsyncTask*

```
Result is an ArrayList<Chat>

for(Chat chat : result){
    if(chat.senderId != mAccount.accId){
        adapter.add(new ChatString(false, chat.chatMessage));
    }else{
        adapter.add(new ChatString(true, chat.chatMessage));
    }
}
```

A brief explanation of what this adapter does:

The adapter suppose to add new "chat bubble" to a listview in its root view.

Can anyone help me with this?

**Edit 1**
I've tried the following solution (still no luck):

```
// Removing the parent.
 if(chat.mLeft){
     textChat.setText(chat.mText); 
 }else{
     View view = (View) wrapper.getParent();
     wrapper.removeView(view);
     wrapper.removeViewAt(1);
     wrapper.addView(thumbPhoto, 0);
     textChat.setText(chat.mText);
 }

 if (row == null) {
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_item, null); <---- CHANGING THIS BIT
 }
```

Comment: `wrapper.addView(thumbPhoto, 0);` thumbPhoto already has a parent, as it is in row.

Comment: What you want to do here is have 2 different layouts, and use getViewTypeCount and getItemViewType to declare 2 different types.

Comment: @njzk2 what are you suggesting? Can you provide an code example?

Comment: it will tell the view recycling process to recycle view only for identical view types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your getView as such:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ChatString chat = getItem(position);
    if (row == null) {
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

         // Here, inflate 2 different layouts
         if(chat.mLeft){
             row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_item, parent, false);
         } else {
             row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_item_right, parent, false);
         }
    }

    wrapper = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.wrapper);

    textChat = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textMessage);
    thumbPhoto = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.thumbPhoto);

    // Here, just set the text
    textChat.setText(chat.mText);
    return row;
}
```

And to indicate the view recycling to provide you with consistent views, add to your adapter:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    ChatString chat = getItem(position);
    if (chat.mLeft) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you... thank you... thank you..... it works... i didn't know there is such thing as getItemViewType & getViewTypeCount....